# What is the most efficient way to get data out of the following JSON object as two separate arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

What is the most efficient way to get data out of the following JSON object as two separate arrays?

```
let dates = [];
let values = [];
```

For example, I want to get [0] index values from each array and save to a dates Arr, and [1] index values and save to a values Arr.

Is there a way to destructure the object and assign variables to each element? or would a for loop within a forEach() function be the best approach?

```
Obj {
"data": [
    [
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-04-01",
      246.3
    ],
    [
      "1947-07-01",
      250.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-10-01",
      260.3
    ]
}
```

**Note:** The JSON object is being retrieved through a fetch API call.

Comment: A loop would work. for loop, foreach, reduce, etc will all do it.

Comment: I would use map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: A loop would be your best shot. You can create one (which wouldn't look so tidy but would do the job), or create two clean ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of pre-sized arrays, a single loop, and index-based destructuring. That should be pretty speedy; it prevents array-resizing and spares you from any of the unnecessary per-iteration (or even multi-iteration) processing/logic that comes along with some of the other approaches.

```js
const data = [
  [
    "1947-01-01",
    243.1
  ],
  [
    "1947-04-01",
    246.3
  ],
  [
    "1947-07-01",
    250.1
  ],
  [
    "1947-10-01",
    260.3
  ]
];

// get data length
let n = data.length;
// initialize output arrays of length n
const dates = new Array(n); 
const values = new Array(n);
// loop, decrementing n
while (n--) {
  // destructure, assigning at corresponding indices in target arrays
  [dates[n],values[n]] = data[n];     
}

console.table({dates, values});
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block}</style><script>console.config({timeStamps:false,maximize:true})</script>
```

Since you expressed an interest in efficiency, here's [a jsbench test](https://jsbench.me/2wl0coig19/1) comparing a few of the competing solutions.

Comment: Thanks @canon , this is a great readable example of imperative code!
I do have one confusion though, in the last iteration of the while loop, the value of n would be 0, which is a falsy value, how come it passes the while condition test?
Side note - I tried running this example and it works :)

Comment: That has to do with the difference between `--n` and `n--`. `--n` returns the value _after_ decrementing while `n--` returns the value _before_ decrementing (that's what we used here). See the [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement). For the last iteration, we tested `1`( truthy) for the condition but `n` would be `0` for the iteration body.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your in-depth answer.  The testing suite was appreciated also.